# How to push java docker image to private repo using gradle-docker-plugin?

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I'm trying to push a docker image using gradle to a private repo. [gradle-docker-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) does exactly that. Using the docker-java-application I can build an image but I can't push it my own repository.

In the debug logging i see the following line:

```
[DEBUG] [com.github.dockerjava.core.command.PushImageResultCallback] ResponseItem(stream=null, status=The push refers to repository [docker.io/project-name/project-app], progressDetail=null, progress=null, id=null, from=null, time=null, errorDetail=null, error=null, aux=null)
```

And the later the breaking error:

```
> Could not push image: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Which makes sense because my configured account is not for docker.io but only my own repository.

My gradle files looks like this:

Buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:7.0.1'
    }
    ...
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.bmuschko.docker-java-application'
}
...
mainClassName = 'com.project.app.Main'
...
docker {
    javaApplication {
        baseImage = 'jre-11.0.11_9-alpine'
        ports = [8080]
        jvmArgs = ['-Xms256m', '-Xmx2048m']
    }
    registryCredentials {
        url = 'https://private.repository.example'
        username = 'user'
        password = 'password'
    }
}
```

I can build and run the image locally, only the push fails. Is this the correct way of configuring the remote repository for the docker-java-application plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
docker login https://private.repository.example --username user --password password
```

And then check that your /.docker/config.json has entries:

```
{
    "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {},
            "https://private.repository.example" : {}
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop.exe"
}
```

After that - remove `"https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}` and restart Docker.
It should default all pushes and pulls with `https://private.repository.example`

Comment: I'm expecting the plugin to do this for me since I'm configuring `registryCredentials`.

Comment: I got that :)
From what I've found - gradle-docker-plugin loads the /.docker/config.json and takes the default repo from there, registryCredentials.url is not working
https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/788